# Custom deleter for shared_ptr that expects an address of pointer

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Many C APIs provide release functions that take a `**p` which besides releasing the resource also sets the pointer to `NULL`.
I want to wrap such C API calls with a `boost::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter.

Here's an example with FFMPEG:

```
AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc(); // allocate resource
// Do stuff with frame
av_frame_free(&frame)              // free resource
```

To leverage RAII, I can rewrite this like so:

```
AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
boost::shared_ptr<AVFrame*> frame_releaser(&frame, av_frame_free);
// Do stuff with frame
```

Note that the `shared_ptr<>` is of type `<AVFrame*>` and not `<AVFrame>` as the pointer type.
This approach requires me to hold the resource and the releaser separately, which has several drawbacks:

1. `frame` may be changed externally causing a leak.
2. It requires 2 variable instead of one, which makes the code more bug prone.

I'd like to use a single `shared_ptr` variable to both hold the resource *and* release it when needed.

In the spirit of `boost::ref`, I'm looking to write or use a **generic** `address_of_arg_wrapper` for the deleter that will allow me to write somthing like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<AVFrame> frame_handle(av_frame_alloc(), address_of_arg_wrapper(av_frame_free));
// Do stuff with frame_handle.get()
```

or

```
boost::shared_ptr<AVFrame> frame_handle(av_frame_alloc(), address_of_arg_wrapper<av_frame_free>());
// Do stuff with frame_handle.get()
```

It is important that the wrapper be generic and accept any pointer (ref) type, so it can be used with any such API functions.
I also do not want to specify the types.

Does Boost have such a utility?
If not, then how can one write such a generic functor?

**EDIT - Solution for completeness:**

This solution is based on [@R. Martinho Fernandes's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17404688/135862).

1. It includes a template function to create  the template functor, so that there's no need to specify the template types.
2. The code depends on `boost::decay`. A version that just holds a `Fun fun;` member also worked for simple cases I tested.
3. I changed the name to `arg_ref_adaptor()`. Better name suggestions are welcome!

Here's the code:

```
#include <boost\type_traits\decay.hpp>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Given a function or callable type 'fun', returns an object with 
// a void operator(P ptr) that calls fun(&ptr)
// Useful for passing C API function as deleters to shared_ptr<> which require ** instead of *.
template <typename Fun>
struct arg_ref_adaptor_functor 
{
public:
   arg_ref_adaptor_functor(Fun fun): fun(fun) {}

   template <typename P> 
   void operator()(P ptr) 
   { fun(&ptr); }

private:
   typename boost::decay<Fun>::type fun;
};

template <typename Fun>
inline arg_ref_adaptor_functor<Fun> arg_ref_adaptor(Fun fun)
{  return arg_ref_adaptor_functor<Fun>(fun); }
```

Usage:

```
boost::shared_ptr<AVFrame> frame_handle(::av_frame_alloc() 
                                       ,arg_ref_adaptor(::av_frame_free));
// Do stuff with frame_handle.get()
// The resource will be released using ::av_frame_free() when frame_handle
// goes out of scope.
```

Comment: IMO you should typedef boost::shared_ptr since C++11 has std::shared_ptr, and you'll want to minimise migration effort when upgrading your compiler.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'll just keep namespace clear. To batch replace boost::shared_ptr to std::shared_ptr can be done in one second. while mixing namespace is dangerous.

Comment: @billz: that's cool; so long as we bear migration in mind.

Comment: I was deliberating whether to mention `boost::shared_ptr` vs. `std::shared_ptr` but decided that it was not really the point here. Using Boost made it obvious that a solution from Boost (a-la `boost::ref` would be acceptable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the pointer to null is pointless since the `shared_ptr` already guarantees the pointer will never be visible again after destruction. So the code only needs to pass along an address to please the `av_frame_free` function. I suggest simply writing a function object that passes along the address of its argument.

```
template <typename Fun>
struct address_of_arg_wrapper {
public:
    address_of_arg_wrapper(Fun fun) : fun(fun) {}

    template <typename P>
    void operator()(P ptr) {
        fun(&ptr);
    }

private:
    typename boost::decay<Fun>::type fun;
};
```

In C++11 a lambda can be used:

```
[](AVFrame* ptr) { av_frame_free(&ptr); }
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I tried to do, but couldn't quite get it :-). Re: the null, that's indeed an API thing not a requirement. Why use `boost::decay` and not just `Fun fun`? Also, isn't there something similar already in Boost?

Comment: @AdiShavit: [`boost::decay`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/decay.html) is used to allow `Fun` to be expressed as `void()` rather than having to use `void(&)()`.  This provides the same syntax users of `boost::function` would expect.

Comment: @Tanner Sansbury: Sorry, I don't understand your answer.